# parameters of ldap Authentication

Tags: python, django, ldap

i'm need your help. Don't minus this post, an only explain please.

I try to connect my django site to ldap, i find the official example, but need help parameters.

i can use IP in this string :

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.example.com"
```

what need to write to this string?

```
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=django-agent,dc=example,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "phlebotinum"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=users,dc=example,dc=com",
```

where i can take `cn=django-agent,dc=example,dc=com` ?

and what need to write user?

```
ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
```

if i write him in the top?

and again :

```
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=django,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=groupOfNames)"
)
```

need to write the same parametes?

Explain me plese!!

link : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-auth-ldap/1.1.4

Comment: All the answers you seek are included in the documentation you yourself posted: http://pythonhosted.org/django-auth-ldap ...